# Is there any for good Java lib for playing with Sockets connections?

Tags: java, sockets

Search for good Java lib for playing with Sockets connections - Is there any such lib or how to play with sockets from pure Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/index.html) is the best place to start. You'll probably want the [All About Sockets](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) section. Then, of course, there's the [JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/package-frame.html) for the `java.net` package.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of playing are you wanting to do with sockets?  The [java.net package](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/package-summary.html) (part of standard Java) contains several classes for dealing with sockets, most notably the [Socket](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org/) which is easier to start with. MINA provides a good abstraction level for working with sockets, here an [example of a time server](http://mina.apache.org/mina-v20-quick-start-guide.html) with a few lines of code using it.

You need to check [Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/index.html) if you want fully understand Java approach though.

Comment: +1 for MINA, I'm using it (in fact, to make my Java interface to the ns-3 network simulator easier to use, I have implemented it, but only for UDP at the moment -- I'm working on TCP support)